Which modern camera for vintage OM-Zuiko lenses?
I used to practice analog photography as a hobby. However, my current work and lifestyle prevent me from spending the time that this hobby requires. I gave away my development material and do not have the space for a darkroom (even small) anymore.
Nevertheless, I kept a bunch of vintage lenses (and cameras) from that time. My preferred ones where a set of OM-Zuiko lenses that I grew very fond of: 28mm/f2.8, 50mm/f1.4, 50mm/f1.8, 100mm/f2.8. These were the ones that accompanied me on my important trips.
I have heard that you can use vintage lenses on modern digital cameras through adapters. However, I completely ignore where to start.
Is there a specific camera model that works better with OM-Zuiko vintage lenses? Would the adapter negatively impact image quality, and by how much?
I suppose that there are many drawbacks to doing this. However, I would be very happy to just be able to use these lenses on a modern camera and obtain very good results. Keep in mind that I have never done digital photography other than shooting with phone cameras (which is frustrating because of the lack of a viewfinder). Therefore, the availability of accurate picture data, GPS positioning, etc., is not something I require.

TL;DR: a full frame mirrorless body would probably be your best option to use adapted OM-mount lenses.

Is there a specific camera model that works better with OM-Zuiko vintage lenses?

Well, the lenses will behave more like you're used to them behaving on 35mm film if you get a full frame body. If you get a crop body, they'll frame more tightly and may not be useful for the same things you used them for on a film body.
And it's not really about specific camera models.  Specific camera mounts make it easier to use the lenses with an adapter that doesn't require a glass element in it. Basically, any digital mount with a registration or flange distance that's shallower than Olympus OM's (46mm) with a bigger or same sized mount throat would let you use a simple tube adapter.
In practical terms, this means any mirrorless body and Canon EOS  mount and Pentax K-mount dSLRs (Sony A-mount/Minolta AF mount is the right depth, but the wrong diameter).
Nikon F mount dSLRS would require a lens mount replacement to avoid requiring a glass element in the adapter, and that would only work for certain lenses. Or you'd need an adapter with an optical element in it to retain focus to infinity (i.e., holding the lens farther out from the body than it's designed to be held is like using a macro extension tube: you gain close focus ability, but lose focus capability at the far distance end of the range).

Would the adapter negatively impact image quality, and by how much?

If it's a simple hollow tube, it won't impact image quality.

This is an image I took of Barry Sonnenfeld and Ellen Green at the 2008 San Diego Comic-Con with an Olympus OM-mount Zuiko Auto-S MC 50mm f/1.2 adapted to a Canon 5Dii dSLR [full frame body] with a simple Fotodiox adapter ring.
If an adapter has a glass element in it, though, it depends on the quality of the element. Cheap sub-$100 adapters with a glass element tend to impact image quality as much as a sub-$100 piece of glass will.
Keep in mind, adapting has challenges. Because the lens is fully mechanical and cannot electronically communicate with a digital camera body, you won't have autofocus, or aperture control from the camera body (i.e., you can only shoot in M or aperture-priority mode): you have to set both focus and aperture manually with the lens's rings. The camera must also be able to perform accurate stop-down metering, and your adapter needs to be able to engage the DoF stop on the lens so that when you adjust the aperture ring, the lens actually stops down (wide-open aperture for composition and only stopping down while taking the image is the default behavior on most SLRs, film or digital).
Lastly, most digital bodies do not have a split-circle focus screen or any of the usual manual focus aids of a film SLR, because autofocus is now standard. Mirrorless does have the advantages of using liveview even in the viewfinders, so you can use manual focus aids like magnification and focus peaking: things a dSLR can only do on the back LCD of the body, not in the viewfinder.
See also: Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?

The short and simple answer: get any APS-C or full frame mirrorless camera, they're all good. APS-C is cheaper, full frame if you don't want the "built in" 1.5-1.6x crop factor of APS-C.
Why mirrorless? Because they have a short registration distance, and can therefore be used with a glassless adapter, meaning essentially no image quality degradation.

I have used the OM 50mm f1.8 lens with a variety of the now discontinued Olympus four thirds cameras. The adapter has no glass but also no contacts mechanical or electrical, however they are still on ebay for around £10.

You can also get adapters that do have at least some connections for the camera and lens to communicate. It all depends upon which mount the lenses are in, which mount the camera is in, and what the adapter includes.

With a registration distance of 46mm and a smaller throat diameter (also 46mm), OM lenses might be usable on Canon EF (44mm/54mm throat diameter) with glassless adapters. The Nikon F mount (46.5mm/ 44mm throat) certainly is.
